# Perl, how to get pid of threads from exec, system, open functions on Win32 and Unix

Tags: perl, fork, system, pid

This question isn't really new, https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=620645, but I did not find a working answer for my problem. In short, I want to get access to the PID of a thread/process created by a function such as system, exec or open. One that I found using the open function `my $pid = open my $fhOut, "| the command ", or die ...;`, in Linux, the actual PID value according to the `ps` command is `$pid + 2`, but in wind32, the actual PID is a negative number (like -1284). In both cases, the PID returned by the open function is not the same as $pid!!

Likewise, the pid returned by `my $pid = system 1, "command params"` does not match the PID from the operating system. Can someone explain please? What is the proper way to quit an endless loop program called from open or system functions. 
This is my test code:

```
my $pid = fork();
if( $pid == 0 ) 
{
  my $mimperf_pid = open my $cmd, "mimperf -C  $db > results/mimperf/mimperf.log |" or die $!;
  sleep(10);
  print $mimperf_pid;
  kill 'KILL', $mimperf_pid; 
  exit 0;
}
```

In this code, I am trying to kill the thread ($mimperf_pid) created via the `open` function, but it did not succeed.

Comment: `system` returns the exit code, not a pid.

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu Linux, and the `kill` command in your example worked fine here (for testing, I replaced `mimperf -C  $db > results/mimperf/mimperf.log |` with a custom perl script)

Comment: @choroba, Actually, `system 1, ...` is a special Windows-only syntax to run a program in the background that does return a PID.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, TIL. It's not mentioned in [system](http://p3rl.org/system), but I found it in [perlport](http://p3rl.org/perlport).

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` isn't supported by Windows, so Perl (poorly) emulates it using threads. These virtual processes have negative PIDs. You should avoid `fork()` on Windows if you can, using threads instead if nothing else.

This isn't pertinent to your question, though. While the PID returned by `fork` is negative, the PID returned by `open` is not.

---

One should generally avoid two-arg `open`, so

```
open my $cmd, "foo bar |"
```

is equivalent to

```
open my $cmd, "-|", "foo bar"
```

And that's equivalent to

```
open my $cmd, "-|", "cmd", "/x", "/c", "foo bar"
```

You are launching a shell to execute a shell command, and it's the PID of the shell that `open` returns.

Same goes with `system 1, $shell_cmd`.

That means that the Ctrl-Break signal is being sent to the shell. (That's what Perl sends in lieu of non-existent SIGKILL.)

Now, I don't have `mimperf` so I used an alternative program instead of `mimperf` (`perl`), and it received the Ctrl-Break signal as well as the shell. So if `mimperf` didn't exit, maybe it's because it isn't responsive to Ctrl-Break?

---

If you want to avoid the shell, you will need to do the output redirection yourself. For that, I recommend [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run). It handles timeouts too.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "mimperf", "-C", $db ],
   ">", "results/mimperf/mimperf.log",
   timeout(10);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a comma behind `]` in your code above?